# Counting in bases higher which don't have letters attached to them

Tags: java, count, numbers, radix

Hello fellow StackOverflowers, today I pose a strange question.

As all of you know, there are different ways in which to count (in terms of bases)

For base 2 (a.k.a binary), one would count as follows

0000 = (2^3 x 0) + (2^2 x 0) + (2^1 x 0) + (2^0 x 0) = 0

0001 = (2^3 x 0) + (2^2 x 0) + (2^1 x 0) + (2^0 x 1) = 1

0010 = (2^3 x 0) + (2^2 x 0) + (2^1 x 1) + (2^0 x 0) = 2

0011 = (2^3 x 0) + (2^2 x 0) + (2^1 x 1) + (2^0 x 1) = 3

...and so on...

---

When we reach bases higher than 10, such as 16 (a.k.a hexadecimal) we use letters to represent values:

For example:

200 base 16 = C8  ---> http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-hex-converter (if you dont believe me ;))

---

However, how will we count in bases higher than letters allow? (base 37+)

I wrote a simple java program to illustrate my point:

```
public class Testing {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int base = 1;base<=50;base++){
        System.out.println("===========================Base " + base + "===============================");
        for (int value=1; value<=50; value++){
              System.out.println(value + " base " + base + " is equal to: " + Integer.toString(value, base));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here are some snippets of the output of my program:

```
40 base 36 is equal to: 14
41 base 36 is equal to: 15
42 base 36 is equal to: 16
43 base 36 is equal to: 17
44 base 36 is equal to: 18
45 base 36 is equal to: 19
46 base 36 is equal to: 1a
47 base 36 is equal to: 1b
48 base 36 is equal to: 1c
49 base 36 is equal to: 1d
50 base 36 is equal to: 1e

28 base 37 is equal to: 28
29 base 37 is equal to: 29
30 base 37 is equal to: 30
31 base 37 is equal to: 31
32 base 37 is equal to: 32
33 base 37 is equal to: 33
34 base 37 is equal to: 34
35 base 37 is equal to: 35
36 base 37 is equal to: 36
37 base 37 is equal to: 37
38 base 37 is equal to: 38
39 base 37 is equal to: 39
40 base 37 is equal to: 40
41 base 37 is equal to: 41
42 base 37 is equal to: 42
43 base 37 is equal to: 43
44 base 37 is equal to: 44
45 base 37 is equal to: 45
46 base 37 is equal to: 46
47 base 37 is equal to: 47
48 base 37 is equal to: 48
49 base 37 is equal to: 49
50 base 37 is equal to: 50
```

---

As you can see, base 37+ doesn't work.

Is there anyway to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Well. What system do you want to use? Do you want to use greek letters? Alien symbols? [Grinning cat face with smiling eyes](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F638/index.htm)?

Comment: You can only fix stuff that is broken. But there is nothing broken here. The question is simply that you want a system that has enough "symbols", so that you can express 37+ different values, without the need to combine "symbols". In other words: you are talking about encoding information. And there are plenty of ways to do that. For example, you could differentiate between lower case and uppercase (so a would mean something else as A). As said: you can define whatever you want.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: there is no restriction on the characters to the ASCII characters. Encode in Unicode and you can continue for a much larger base-value. If this is still not sufficient, you will need to invent a way to display the digits differently, maybe each digit is written as `_digit` where `_` is a seperation char and digit is a multicharacter value. In the end, is is only a mathematically correct short-form for a B-adic(sp?) term (B-adischer Bruch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Character.MAX_RADIX` is equal to `36` (10 digits and 26 letters).

If you want to use higher values for radix, you will have to  write your own method. This should not be too hard. I suggest modifying the source code for `Integer.toString(int, int)`. The code for this method uses this array:

```
final static char[] digits = {
    '0' , '1' , '2' , '3' , '4' , '5' ,
    '6' , '7' , '8' , '9' , 'a' , 'b' ,
    'c' , 'd' , 'e' , 'f' , 'g' , 'h' ,
    'i' , 'j' , 'k' , 'l' , 'm' , 'n' ,
    'o' , 'p' , 'q' , 'r' , 's' , 't' ,
    'u' , 'v' , 'w' , 'x' , 'y' , 'z'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static String DIGITS = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@!#$%&;:";

public static String toString(int i, int base) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (; i > 0; i /= base)
        sb.append(DIGITS.charAt(i % base));
    if (sb.length() == 0)
        sb.append(0);
    return sb.reverse().toString();
}
```